# Is Otto grass saying indirectly don't believe in monogamy?

Tags: meaning

Carl Jung asks a question to Otto grass.

> Carl: So you're not a believer in monogamy?
>
> Otto: For a neurotic like myself I can't possibly imagine a more
>   stressful concept.

Is Otto grass saying indirectly don't believe in monogamy?

Comment: Yes; there is an implied "[That is correct, because]" at the beginning of his response.

Comment: What do you mean by ***don't* believe in**? That he thinks it is a bad idea or convention and is urging someone not to become monogamous? Why are you using the imperative?

Answer (score 1):

In his answer, Otto Grass is acknowledging the concept of **monogamy**, but saying it is not suitable for him to practice.

So, to answer your question, Grass *believes* **monogamy** exists, but will not practice it, in the same way that vegeterians *believe* meat exists, but will not eat it.